# Setting app permissions for Detox iOS tests not working properly

Tags: jestjs, react-native-ios, detox

I'm having issues with this and other methods of setting permissions for iOS in Detox. My app will initially launch with the notification popup, then if I dismiss the popup, the app will relaunch without the notification, but it is still requiring manual intervention. My code in init.js is:

```
beforeAll(async () => {
  await detox.init(undefined, { launchApp: false });
  await device.launchApp({ permissions: { notifications: 'YES' } });
});
```

I have also tried the alternative approach found in this thread yielding the same results: https://github.com/wix/Detox/pull/2009

Comment: Do you have `applesimutils` installed?

Comment: Yes I do. We have resolved this issue with a combination of approaches found in the github thread I linked. Thanks

Comment: You should add an answer with what you did, and mark it as resolved.

Comment: Can you please share your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix here:

https://github.com/wix/Detox/pull/2009#issuecomment-648971528

> With this new integration with jest-circus. How should I launch the app with the permissions I need?

> I got my tests working again by overriding the initDetox function in my CustomDetoxEnvironment like this:

```
async initDetox() {
    const instance = await this.detox.init(undefined, {launchApp: false});
    await instance.device.launchApp({permissions: {notifications: 'YES'}});
    return instance;
  }
```

This ended up working for me